# How to use where argument in graphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have this running query:

```
{
  ArticleGalleriesCollection(limit: 2, locale: "en", where: {articleTitle: "Hello"}) {
    items {
      articleTitle
      articleGalleryType {
        type
        width
        height
      }
      articleAssetsElementsCollection(limit: 100) {
        items {
          fileName
          url
          contentType
          width
          height
          size
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to update my where argument telling graphQL to filter in only 
Articles in ArticleGalleriesCollection having articleGalleryType with a type="standard"

How am I supposed to update my query?

Schema :
Every item in ArticleGalleriesCollection has a 1:1 articleGalleryType with a type attribute

Comment: Well, how can we help if we don't know your schema or what your GraphQL server is?

Comment: Updated the question ... thought schema def could be straight forward from the query. Sorry. Dont get exactly why specifying the server...

Comment: That doesn't help at all. The schema will also detail the `where` clauses. For example you currently have `where: {articleTitle: "Hello"}` but I cannot suggest how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

What can be asked with graphql depends directly from schema, server (resolvers)

If your api doesn't support filtering on `articleGalleryType` then no sense to construct not working query.

There is no general standard (ready, built in) for filtering - it's your server's responsibility (business logic).

Comment: Yes ok but if I say this is a running query. Meaning successfully running... How many data structures can you imagine from that? So let’s suppose it does support filtering on articleGalleryType. How can I possibly write the where filter argument? I'm obviously a newbie with graphQL so I'm missing some concepts... But still I'm not so sure that the question is so broad and unanswerable taking into account that I'm starting with a running example...

Comment: too many possibilities - [warning](https://graphqlme.com/2018/05/05/beware-of-complex-filtering-in-graphql/) - you should know what client should be able to ask for - other requirements for MVP, other for fully universal SaaS solution ... and different amount of time/money required